# No User matches the given query. Page Not found 404?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

In my blog website I want to open another user's profile on clicking one of the links. But it keeps on showing 404 error saying No user matches the given query.

Here's that link in a `base.html`

```
<a href="{% url 'blogapp:userprofile' username=view.kwargs.username %}">{{ view.kwargs.username }}</a>
```

Here's my `urls.py` pattern for the function-

```
path('userprofile/<str:username>/',views.userprofile,name='userprofile'),
```

Here's my function `views.py`

```
@login_required
def userprofile(request,username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User,username='username')

    return render(request,'blogapp/userprofile.html',{'user':user})
```

here's my template file

```
{% extends 'blogapp/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

          <div class="row">
            <img  src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
          <div class="details">
            <h2>{{ user.username }}</h2>
            <p>{{ user.email }}</p>
          </div>
          </div>
          <p style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 138px;">{{ user.profile.description }}</p>
          <hr>


{% endblock %}
```

`{{ view.kwargs.username }}` gives the perfect username that I search for. But problem is somewhere in the userprofile view. It goes to the perfect route `http://127.0.0.1:8000/userprofile/username/` but it still shows a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your views you are passing `username` as a string, whereas it should be a variable that's being passed inside the `userprofile` function.

```
@login_required
def userprofile(request,username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User,username=username)

    return render(request,'blogapp/userprofile.html',{'user':user})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@login_required
def userprofile(request,username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User,username='username')

    return render(request,'blogapp/userprofile.html',{'user':user})
```

Shoudld be this

```
@login_required
def userprofile(request,username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User,username=username)

    return render(request,'blogapp/userprofile.html',{'user':user})
```

Username on line 2 is being treated as a string instead of variable.