# No user matches given query even though the user exists

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I'm fairly new to Django and am working on making user profile pages accessible by using the user's username in the url, e.g. mysite.com/profile/someusername

I'll be having links to the profile in a couple places, but the first place I'm experimenting on is in my navbar to access the logged-in user's page.

**base.html**

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'fillups:user_profile' username=user.username %}" class="btn btn-simple">Overview</a>
```

This correctly displays the currently logged-in user's name, for the case of this example we'll user the username **seconduser**

This is the url pattern I'm using for this:

```
path('profile/<str:username>/',views.UserProfile.as_view(),name='user_profile')
```

So far, the navbar will display the username, seconduser, and when I click the button I'm brought to the url /profile/seconduser/, which is what I want.

The problem is, I'm not able to now use the username in my view to query the objects for the given user. Here is what I have for this view so far

**views.py**

```
class UserProfile(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'fillups/user_profile.html'
    slug_field = "username"
    slug_url_kwarg = "username"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserProfile, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        usr = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get("username"))
        overview_stats = {
            'total_cars': Car.objects.filter(username=usr).count(),
            'total_fillups': Fillup.objects.filter(username=self.request.user).count(),
            'total_distance': Fillup.objects.filter(username=self.request.user).aggregate(Sum('trip_distance')),
            'total_gallons': Fillup.objects.filter(username=self.request.user).aggregate(total_gallons = Round(Sum('gallons'),4)),
            'avg_price': Fillup.objects.filter(username=self.request.user).aggregate(avg_price = Round(Avg('price_per_gallon'),3)),
            'total_spent': sum_total_sale(Fillup.objects.filter(username=self.request.user)),
            'avg_mpg': avg_mpg(Fillup.objects.filter(username=self.request.user))
        }
        context['stats'] = overview_stats
        context['active_cars'] = Car.objects.filter(status='Active').filter(username=self.request.user)
        context['last_10_fillups'] = Fillup.objects.filter(username=self.request.user).order_by('-date')[:10]
        return context
```

For now, everything in the overview_stats dict is what I originally had when I was just querying stuff for the logged-in user, where there was just a simple "myprofile" url. The problem I'm having her is that the get_object_or_404 isn't finding the user. I know that username=self.kwargs.get("username") is getting 'seconduser' like it should be, but for some reason I just can't get the user.

For some extra info, here is one of my models:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    model_year = models.IntegerField(choices=MODEL_YEARS)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS,default='Active')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And in the initial Django tutorial I did, the instructor said it is best to extend the user model so it's easier to make changes, so I have this in a separate app, accounts/models.py

```
class User(auth.models.User,auth.models.PermissionsMixin):

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)
```

I've tried using the method in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013098/django-username-in-url-instead-of-id) which is why I have the slug field stuff in my view currently, and while my question is essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57538717/no-user-matches-the-given-query-page-not-found-404)

I've been stuck on this all night and would really appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Just to be totally clear. Are you trying to find the current user or “seconduser” vía `get_object_or_404()` in `get_context_data()`?

Comment: "seconduser"! I left the self.request.user stuff in there as that's what I used to have in the view. Once I'm able to figure this out I'll update all those queries to filter by the user found in the get_object_or_404()

Answer (score 0):

Remove the the `self` from `self.kwargs.get("username")`. It should be `kwargs.get("username")`.

`kwargs` is an argument not on object property.